# How to add a every two elements in the array of objects in java script and return the same array of objects

Tags: javascript

const sampleData =  [{
"key1": 10.0,
"key2": 0.0
},
{
"key1": 20.5,
"key2": 0.0
}, {
"key1": 30.0,
"key2": 0.0
},
{
"key1": 30.0,
"key2": 0.0
},
]
Explainantion - adding key1 and returning the same original array.

Need to add the key1 of first object with next object and return the same array of objects

Result should look like

```
const sampleData =  [{
            "key1": 30.5,
            "key2": 0.0
        },
        {
            "key1": 50.5,
            "key2": 0.0
        }, {
            "key1": 60.0,
            "key2": 0.0
        },
{
            "key1": 30.0,
            "key2": 0.0
        },
    ]
```

Comment: hello ABC, please provide any codes you've attempted so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to follow, but it looks like you are just adding each key1 value, to the previous key1 value.

The easiest way to do this would be to use reduce. Off the top of my head it would be something like:

```
const result = sampleData.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const lastKey = acc.lastKey
  return { lastKey: item.key1, result: […acc.result, { …item, key1: item.key1 + lastKey } ]
}, { lastKey: 0, result:[]} ).result
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this for errors